# How to access class in another project using eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing android app using eclipse for this I am creating data access layer as java project. Now I am trying to access this class from android app. So I have added the java project to build path of android project. Now I can able to access the class by importing that . But while running the app I am getting the ClassNotFoundException.

It may seems duplicate but I am new to eclipse and java and I did not understand what they are trying to explain in other questions. So I need help here.

Comment: I think you need to Put the Jar file for(datalayer) in Libs folder

Comment: I have added jar file to lib by right click on lib and using import only src I have added. But still getting the same error.

Comment: I also tried like Properties-->Libraried-->addExternalJar then checked that jar file in order and export tab but still not working.

Comment: copy the jar file of your Project into Libs folder

Comment: Thanks,I have done this also but no luck..

Comment: I copied jar to libs and rightclick on that and selected the addtobuidpath but this also gives the same exception. But while checking the reference library that has my class inside that jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Please put the **JAR** file for **DataAcessLayer** Project in **Libs** folder of your **Android Project**

Answer (score 0):

Export your Java-project into a JAR. Specifically exporting only the `src`-folder. Then place the generated JAR on your Android-project under its `libs`-folder. It should be automatically added to your build path, else, right-click on your JAR, then `Build Path > Add to Build Path`.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on project > Export > java  > Jar File > your project > Finish
- Copy that jar and insert into libs folder and then Build Path > Add to Build Path